# Using dc.js (d3.js) and trying to highlight the x axis at 0

Tags: css, d3.js, dc.js

I want to highlight the xaxis at the value 0 so it's easy to see when values are going negative.  I'm trying to do this in a renderlet.  I can see tell that the x axis is at 0 when the y1 attribute value is equal to the y2 attribute values.  So in the renderlet I'm trying to select the lines, get the y1, y2 values and then when they are equal apply something to the line to make it stand out.  Has anyone does this?  Is there any easier way.  I've got pictures of the element and my selector.  I just can't get the y1, y2 attributes from the selector in the renderlet.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your statement that:

> x axis is at 0 when the y1 attribute value is equal to the y2
>   attribute values

because you are looking at horizontal gridlines.  The y1 will **always** be equal to y2, that's a flat horizontal line.

That said, to find them:

```
d3.selectAll('.grid-line.horizontal line').each(function(d){
    var self = d3.select(this);
    if (self.attr('y1') === self.attr('y2')){
        console.log('do something special');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're looking for the grid line that corresponds to the x axis, i.e. the line y=0, you can find that by using the y scale. Use @Mark's code but compare `y1` with `chart.y()(0)` instead of `y2` - as he points out, y1 always equals y2.